# How can I optimize an animation in Processing, and keep it from leaving a trail of images?

Tags: animation, optimization, processing

I am creating a model of a solar system in processing, and after removing the background I noticed the planets were leaving a trail of their image behind them. The program runs fine when the background is back in, but I want to add a lot more and I am sure this is inefficient and will bog things down.

I am very new to processing, and I am really not sure how to solve this. Maybe delete previous images after a delay to create a shortened trail?

These are just the parts I think are important cherry picked from the code, this is just the example of one planet. Sorry if the code is clunky, any suggestions are happily accepted.

```
Planet p1;

void setup() {
 mercury = loadImage("mercury.png")

 p1 = new Planet(40, random(TWO_PI), 0.05);

}

void draw() {
  //background(0)
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  p1.display1();
  p1.orbit();
}


class Planet  {
  float radius;
  float angle;
  float distance;
  float orbitSpeed;

  Planet(float r, float d, float o) {
     radius = r;
     distance = d;
     orbitSpeed = o;
     angle = random(TWO_PI);
  }

  void orbit() {
    angle = angle + orbitSpeed;
  }

  void display1() {
    pushMatrix();
    rotate(angle);
    translate(distance, 0);
    imageMode(CENTER);
    image(mercury, radius, radius, 10, 10);
    popMatrix();
  }
}
```

I realized that this would probably happen, and I am not sure how to stop it.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about optimizing anything at this point. Store the previous X positions in an ArrayList and redraw them every frame. My guess is that'll be fine for anything you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe is simply the nature of computer graphics; it's how games, operating systems, and hardware displays all work – they clear and redraw everything every frame.

In *Processing*, graphic objects that are pushed to a buffer remain there indefinitely until the buffer is cleared or something is pushed on top of them (this is why the planets are leaving a trail without calling `background()` – previous frames remain in the buffer).

You are worried about the `background()` being inefficient. Don't be, as it's one of the fastest operations (simply sets the value of each pixel, as given by the user).

Processing does provide a `clear()` function, but this is equivalent to `background(0)`.

If you're are still concerned about efficiency and speed, one way to speed up *Processing* is to use the `FX2D` renderer rather than default `AWT` renderer. Another way is cache drawn objects into `PGraphics` objects to prevent successive rasterization (since your planets are image files and not drawn with processing, you needn't worry about this).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is simple enough that it doesn't need optimisations at this stage.
As micycle mentions, you are are drawing an image at a translated position, pretty similar to [blitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_blit).

In terms of the trails, one common trick you could use is not clear the screen completely, but draw a transparent rectangle as the background. The more transparency, the longer the trails.

Here's a tweaked version of your code:

```
// planet object
Planet p1;
// planet texture
PImage mercury;

void setup() {
  size(300, 300);
  // draw image from center
  imageMode(CENTER);
  // clear to black one
  background(0);
  // remove strokes (we'll use rect() later)
  noStroke();
  // set the fill to black but with 9/255 transparency (~3.5% transparent)
  fill(0,9);
  // init texture
  mercury = loadImage("mercury.png");
  // init planet
  p1 = new Planet(40, random(TWO_PI), 0.05);
}

void draw() {
  // draw a transparent rectangle instead of completely clearing the screen
  rect(0,0,width,height);
  // render planet
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  p1.display1();
  p1.orbit();
}


class Planet {
  float radius;
  float angle;
  float distance;
  float orbitSpeed;

  Planet(float r, float d, float o) {
    radius = r;
    distance = d;
    orbitSpeed = o;
    angle = random(TWO_PI);
  }

  void orbit() {
    angle = angle + orbitSpeed;
  }

  void display1() {
    pushMatrix();
    rotate(angle);
    translate(distance, 0);
    image(mercury, radius, radius, 10, 10);
    popMatrix();
  }
}
```

It's an efficient quick'n'dirty hack as you won't need to store previous position and redraw multiple times, however it has it limitations in terms of the flexibility of the trails. Hopefully tweaking the `fill()` alpha parameter will get you the desired effect.

Later on if you're drawing many many many planets it things start running slow have a peak at [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/). Profile the CPU and see the methods that take the longest to complete and focus on those. Don't need to optimise everything, just the slowest calls. Remember that Processing have multiple renderers: `JAVA2D` is the default one, but there's also `FX2D` and `P2D`/`P3D` and they will behave differently. I strongly recommend optimising at the last moment (otherwise code might be less flexible and readable and will slow down development/iteration).